# Using map function of jquery to alert the values of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JobSeeker Registration Page </title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


   <script type="text/javascript" src="try.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div>
 <form>
 <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="First" /> First
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sm" /> Submit
</form>
</div>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //alert("hello");

 $("#sm").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchIDs =
    $(".cb:checked").map(function(){
      return $(this).attr('value');;
    }).get();
    alert(searchIDs.join(','));
    });

});
```

I am trying to alert the values of the checkbox on to the browser. But no data is coming. Could anybody please tell me what is the problem with the above code.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't added a class called .cb to your inputs so your selector is never picking them up.

Try this:

```
$("input[name=cb]:checked")
```

Or add the missing class:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb" class="cb" value="First" /> First
```